# Maven uses large amount of memory when packaging jars

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I'm developing a project with spring cloud, this project has many shared public dependencies,

While doing packaging with command `mvn clean package` to package modules from the whole project to each executable jar.

Observing by command `free -h` I can see that available memory will suddenly disappear while building with maven.

Which means, maven will use large amount of memory (over 3GB) to do this job.

In this case, my server will sometimes crash while trying to repackaging projects.

The total size of this project's jars is less than 1GB, and the shared dependencies are simple and quick to build, I have tried to gather those shared modules into one complex module, the memory usage will reduce to less than 1.5GB. But in this way, All my modules will import many unnecessary dependencies.

Is there any ways to reduce the memory usage of maven？

Comment: First please show your pom files ... which Maven version you are using etc. ? Can you please describe how you measured the memory consumption of Maven via `free`?

Comment: @khmarbaise There is nothing else in my little server , so I assume that all the abnormal usage of memory should be caused by maven. Yesterday I have tried this, It may be solved by adding environment veriable `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms200m -Xmx200m -Xss1m"` and the memory usage will reduce to less than 300M.

Comment: Please show which JDK you are using etc. Memory measurment via `free` does not work. Also Maven version etc. is important... to know... using `-Xsss1m` not really the right way...also `-Xms..`? How many RAM do you have in your machine? etc. there are so many factor which are in that equation... I can't help here...if don't answer the questions...

Comment: @khmarbaise jdk version is `1.8.0_291` maven version is `3.8.1`,and the total RAM of my server is 4GB, I have some other applications already used about 2GB of RAM by setting `-Xms` and `-Xmx`. When maven tried to run `mvn clean package`, the maven process will some times stuck there and CPU will burn to 100%, the server will never response anything.

Comment: @khmarbaise However, by setting that environment above, this kind of situation never show again. Also, when the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` parameters are setting to a quite low value, maven will throw `Out of Memory` exception, so I think maybe my problem is caused by the uncontrolled usage of RAM when compiling by maven?

Comment: First this JDK version is not the most recent. Second using 3.8.1 is also not the most recent one. If the process stucks there are other things which are wrong.. So first check the whole build which Plugin versions you are using ...also what about your unit- and maybe integration tests? This means you are trying to fix the symptom instead of finding the root cause...